# Vue draggable sort only if chosen to

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuedraggable

I'm trying to make sort of a folder and file system in Vue.

**What I want it to do**

When user selects an item and drags it over another item it shows 2 divs. One div says "swap positions" and the other "put into folder". Depending on which od these divs the user lets go of the mouse button the chosen action would be carried out.

**What it does**

Vue dragable just autosorts the items when I drag one over the other. No events like mouseover can be detected to show the mentioned divs.

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-blackburn-9zqjb?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - A good resource for this is https://codesandbox.io

Comment: Added a simple example to my question. Hopefully it is understandable...

Answer (score 1):

This will not resolve your problem, but will help you a lot: Because you drag "file" by clicking and holding with your mouse, don't use `@mouseenter` or other `@mouse...`. Instead of use `@drag...start/over/enter`. And so you can print your red and green zone if you are on folder by clicking a file:

```
<div
  class="item folder"
  @dragover="
    callMe();  /*you can for instance call method in METHODS part too*/
    actions = true;
  "
  @mouseleave="actions = false" /*works just if you are not holding a file woth the mouse*/
>
```